# Proper way force refresh of window in GTK+ 3 using PyGObject?

Tags: pygtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm writing my first GTK+ 3 application in Python using PyGObject.

I have a task where I want user to click on a Start button and then I want update a text field with a count down that displays "3", "2", "1", "Go!" in succession with a pause in between.

If within the button callback method I change the text in between pauses it only shows the final change which I learned is because the window is only redrawn when it gets back to the main loop.  My thought was then that I needed to force it to redraw.

I found some old PyGTK examples to do this using:

```
while Gtk.events_pending():
    Gtk.main_iteration()
```

and now it kind of works but it dosen't reddraw the unpressed button until the 2 is displayed and in a different version it always misses drawing the 3.  Maybe the events are not yet pending?  I'm also not sure if this would be the "proper" way to do what I'm trying to do.  I actually have a bunch of linear tasks that need to be conducted after the button is pushed that require screen updates, this is just a simple example.

Here is the code as it is now:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk, GLib
import Image
import os, sys
import time

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window=Gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_title("Countdown")
        self.window.set_border_width(10)
        self.window.connect_after('destroy', self.destroy)

        # main container of projct
        self.main_box=Gtk.VBox()
        self.main_box.set_spacing(5)

        # countdown label
        self.countdown_label = Gtk.Label()

        # start button
        self.start_button=Gtk.Button("Start!")

        # add the elements to the window
        self.window.add(self.main_box)
        self.main_box.pack_start(self.countdown_label, False, False, 0)
        self.main_box.pack_start(self.start_button, False, False, 0)

        # connect buttons
        self.start_button.connect_after('clicked', self.start_clicked)

        self.window.show_all()

    def start_clicked(self, button):
        # start the countdown
        count=3
        while count > 0:
            self.countdown(count)
            count = count - 1
            while Gtk.events_pending():
                Gtk.main_iteration()
            time.sleep(2)

        self.countdown_label.set_text("Go!")

    def countdown(self, count):
        self.countdown_label.set_text(str(count))
        print count
        return

    def destroy(window, self):
        Gtk.main_quit()

def main():
    app=GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needing to use Gtk.events_pending() and Gtk.main_iteration() is generally a red flag in terms of GTK+ programming. Fixing this particular example, an asynchronous timeout which does not block the main loop can be used [1]:

```
def start_clicked(self, button):
    self.countdown(3)

def countdown(self, count):
    if count > 0:
        self.countdown_label.set_text(str(count))
        # Manually re-add this callback with a decremented count.
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(2, self.countdown, count - 1)
    else:
        self.countdown_label.set_text("Go!")

    # Return False so the callback is not called repeatedly
    # as we manually re-added the callback ourselves above.
    return False
```

In a real world situation, and as mentioned "a bunch of linear tasks that need to be conducted", the answer depends on the type of task. IO bound tasks which may block the UI can use the Gio library to maintain UI responsiveness [2]. For CPU bound tasks which block the UI, a Python thread [3] can be used in combination with UI update callbacks scheduled with Gdk.threads_add_idle or Gdk.threads_add_timeout [4].

See also:

1. http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/GLib-2.0/functions.html#GLib.timeout_add_seconds
2. http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gio-2.0/
3. https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading
4. http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gdk-3.0/functions.html#Gdk.threads_add_idle

Comment: Thanks Simon for the quick and detailed response.  I had actually tried using Glib.timeout_add at one point but my problem was that after calling the likes of self.countdown(3) the execution in the start_clicked callback continued even though the countdown had not yet finished.  I did not want those lines after the countdown to execute until the countdown had completed.  If it helps the application is a photobooth and I actually don't want the user interacting with the app after hitting start.  It needs to do the countdown, take picture, display picture and repeat 3 times.

Comment: @jeffjv: ok, so it sounds like you need to put the remaining code after the initial call to countdown() into another function. This other function (which takes the picture I presume) would then be called within the timeout callback when the timeout is completed (the block of code in my answer where self.countdown_label.set_text("Go!") is called). Basically think about it as a bunch of chained callbacks with a main loop always running (async programming) rather than a linear set of steps being executed.

Comment: Gdk.threads_add_timeout  and Gdk.threads_add_idle are deprecated you can use the python binding for g_main_context_invoke instead

Comment: @PhillipWood I thought it was gdk_threads_begin/end that are deprecated? The add_timeout/idle functions are not marked as such even in the unstable docs... https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/unstable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk-threads-add-idle

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I thought all the gdk_threads* functions were deprecated

Comment: I don't care if this is gonna be flagged or whatever, love you man, made my night.